# Azure APIM with certificate authentication error using .pfx certificate

Tags: azure, rest, cloud, azure-api-management

Helle, everyone.

I am experiencing issue with configuring APIm operation with InBound policy, which handled calls to remote endpoint. I have saved certificate which was provided to me by external service and using thumbprint in policie. Remote endpoint validates requests using certificate.

```
<policies>
<inbound>
    <base />
    <send-request mode="new" response-variable-name="result" timeout="300" ignore-error="false">
        <set-url>https://ip:port/path</set-url>
        <set-method>POST</set-method>
        <set-header name="Accept" exists-action="override">
            <value>*/*</value>
        </set-header>
        <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
            <value>application/xml</value>
        </set-header>
        <set-body>@(context.Request.Body.As<string>())</set-body>
        <authentication-certificate thumbprint="thubprint" password="password" />
    </send-request>
    <return-response response-variable-name="result" />
</inbound>
<backend>
    <base />
</backend>
<outbound>
    <base />
</outbound>
<on-error>
    <base />
</on-error>
```

But as a response I am getting 500 error

```
send-request (259.918 ms)
{
    "messages": [
        "Error occured while calling backend service.",
        "The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.",
        "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure."
    ]
}
```

Thanks beforehands. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: If you are using self-signed certificates, you will need to disable certificate chain validation for API Management to communicate with the backend system. Otherwise it will return a 500 error code.  [Self-signed certificates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-mutual-certificates#self-signed-certificates)

Comment: [Which thumb print should be used to list the hosted services using windows azure management api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701770/which-thumb-print-should-be-used-to-list-the-hosted-services-using-windows-azure) and [Why does APIM need pfx to securely access backend using client certificate?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/695123/why-does-apim-need-pfx-to-securely-access-backend.html)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT, thank you for the answer. Can you point on how to disable certificate chain validation for API Management?

Comment: As mentioned here: [Self-signed certificates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-mutual-certificates#self-signed-certificates) and [Is disabling Validate certificate chain safe?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/491411/is-disabling-validate-certificate-chain-safe.html)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT, I see that it done for backend policies. Is it possible to make same for inboun processing policies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, adding gist as a community wiki answer to help community members who might face a similar issue.

> But as a response I am getting 500 error

- If you are using self-signed certificates, you will need to **[disable certificate chain validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-mutual-certificates#self-signed-certificates)** for API Management to communicate with the backend system. Otherwise, it will return a 500 error code.

Try the following code snippet taken from the document:

```
$context = New-AzApiManagementContext -resourcegroup 'ContosoResourceGroup' -servicename 'ContosoAPIMService'

New-AzApiManagementBackend -Context  $context -Url 'https://contoso.com/myapi' -Protocol http -SkipCertificateChainValidation $true
```

**Note:** As of now disabling certificate chain validation is only possible for **backend policy**.

You can refer to [Azure API Management - Validate incoming client certificate and Send cert to backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61150546/azure-api-management-validate-incoming-client-certificate-and-send-cert-to-bac), [Is disabling Validate certificate chain safe?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/491411/is-disabling-validate-certificate-chain-safe.html) and [Protect your APIs with Azure API Management](https://aztoso.com/apim/client-certificates-authentication/)